# Angular $parse error when filtering/ordering on hash values that start with integers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash

I have a fairly complex angular orderBy filter structure that works very well with the exception of when the expression passed to the filter function begins with a hash that starts with an integer.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lgubv85/) which should capture the problem nicely.

Using an array in the stucture of:

```
[{'ced8d91c7921a884a131fcc7086239':{'value':'somevalue1'},
  '0a9308d3092d092718e457d927f110': {'value':'anotherval'}},
 {'ced8d91c7921a884a131fcc7086239':{'value':'axxfi'},
  '0a9308d3092d092718e457d927f110': {'value':'zziojasf'}}];
```

and a filter predicate in the structure of '*somehash*.value' will *only* work if the hash begins with a letter.

The reason I am filtering on hash ids and not a more human readable structure is that the data is dynamic and angular does not know ahead of time what the names of the properties are that it needs to filter on.

This error persists when trying to filter in JS using $filter.

Looking through the call stack, the issue appears to occur in the `Lexer.lex` function, specifically here:

```
else if (this.isNumber(ch) || ch === '.' && this.isNumber(this.peek())) {
    this.readNumber();
```

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: There certainly has to be a way around this, but basically keys can't start with a number if you plan on accessing them using dot notation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698792/javascript-object-key-beginning-with-number-allowed I am trying to get yours to work using something like toString.

Comment: Yeah I tried using toString() as well. It's already being evaluated as a string however, which makes me think that any attempts at converting it to a string will fail.

Comment: you could encode the keys to something like base64, granted b64 always starts with a non numeric character which I think it does

Comment: I feel like `{{entry['0a9308d3092d092718e457d927f110'].value}}` is bad practice. There is certainly a better way

Comment: @Ronnie, that's just for a quick demonstration purpose, the actual code is far more elegant :)

Comment: is that and example of the actual data structure?

Comment: The data structure looks similar to that, yes.

Comment: ok and your goal is to be able to sort `entries[0]['examplehash'].value` and `entries[1]['examplehash'].value`?

Comment: It's being used in a data-table format, so each column would need to be sorted. The columns have a separate config data format with an object for each column heading that has a reference to the actual data being listed, so that when you click on the heading, it passes the correct field to be sorted on. A hash is being used since a field could conceivably have the same name.

Comment: are you hashing the object keys or are you getting that from an API? The reason I ask is it may be easier to hash them differently to avoid having the first character be numeric

Comment: The hashes are coming from django. If neccessary, I can add a separate key that prepends a string character to the hash value and use that. It's just not...the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Write a Custom Hash Keys Filter

Instead of fighting with the Lexer or $parse I will always move to a custom filter. This way we can bypass the Lexer and fix our issue, and then go submit a bug to the [Angular Team](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#issue).

**NOTE: This works with AngularJS 1.2.1 which is what was selected in your fiddle. I am not sure if it will work with any current version of AngularJS.**

This is just a simple psuedo associative array sorter that takes a predicate string expression to drill down the values to compare.

We need to push the values in the `arrOfObjects` to our output `arr` to avoid referencing. We can't `angular.copy` because it will fire to many digest cycle and well... vomit.

Below is the filter and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lgubv85/1/) is an updated fiddle.

```
angular.module('orderByFail').filter('orderByHashKey', [
  function orderByHashKeyFilter() {

    // params: array of objects, the property expression as predicate
    //         and reverse
    // NOTE: the property expression is not an Angular expression
    // it is a dot-notation property string expression (ex: obj.key1.key2)
    return function(arrOfObjects, propertyExp, reverse) {

      // if there is no predicate then just return the array
      // the whole reason we are using this is for hash key predicates
      if (typeof propertyExp === 'undefined') return arrOfObjects;

      propertyExp = propertyExp.split('.');
      var len = propertyExp.length;
      var arr = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < arrOfObjects.length; i++) { arr.push(arrOfObjects[i]); }

      arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        var i = 0;

        // drill down to the values we want
        while( i < len ) {
          a = a[propertyExp[i]];
          b = b[propertyExp[i]];
          i++;
        }

        // this is just a slightly faster bitwise solution
        // you can comment this out and use the ternary form below if you prefer
        if (a < b) {
          return -!reverse | 1;
        } else if (a > b) {
          return -!!reverse | 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }

        /*
        if (a < b) {
          return reverse ? 1 : -1;
        } else if (a > b) {
          return reverse ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
        */
      });
      return arr;

    }

  }
]);
```

Comment: Excellent. This is a good idea. I've modified the while function to handle cases where hashes may not exist in certain sorts  
```a = a === undefined ? '' : a[propertyExp[i]];```


```b = b === undefined ? '' : b[propertyExp[i]];```

Comment: Thanks @Duncan. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can write getter function instead of specifying predicate. For example http://jsfiddle.net/c6Ldmphu/2/

```js
(function () {
  angular.module( 'orderByFail', [  
]);
    
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter, $log) {
    $scope.reverse = true;
    $scope.sortColumn2 = '0a9308d3092d092718e457d927f110.value';
    
    $scope.entries = [{'ced8d91c7921a884a131fcc7086239':{'value':'somevalue1'},
                       '0a9308d3092d092718e457d927f110': {'value':'anotherval'}
                     },
                   {'ced8d91c7921a884a131fcc7086239':{'value':'axxfi'},
                    '0a9308d3092d092718e457d927f110': {'value':'zziojasf'}
                   }];
    
    $scope.sort1 = function() {
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        $scope.sortColumn1 = 'ced8d91c7921a884a131fcc7086239.value'
    }
    
     $scope.sort2 = function() {
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        $scope.sortColumn2 = '0a9308d3092d092718e457d927f110.value'
     }
    
     $scope.sort = function(val) {
         var cols = $scope.sortColumn2.split('.');
         angular.forEach(cols, function(col, colKey) {
             val = val[col];
         });
         return val;
     }
}
    
angular
  .module('orderByFail')
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)
  ;
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="orderByFail">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="sort1()">This sort works</button>
    <div ng-repeat="entry in entries | orderBy:sortColumn1:reverse">{{entry['ced8d91c7921a884a131fcc7086239'].value}}</div>
    <button ng-click="sort2()">This sort will error in console</button>
    <div ng-repeat="entry in entries | orderBy: sort:reverse">{{entry['0a9308d3092d092718e457d927f110'].value}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```